# call external javascript function from mxml

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mxml

I am new to flash. But I have some little bit knowledge about what am I doing.
I am developing an application in which I need to pass value of clicked button in external js file which I have added in html file. (html files embeded flash src).

MXML code (function) :

```
private function sendDTMF(tone:String):void {
        JSLog.debug("Sending DTMF tone "+tone);
        ExternalInterface.call("sendDTMF",tone);
        //connectionManager.sendDTMF(tone);
        JSLog.debug("last Send DTMF tone "+tone);

    }
```

This function is working but when I call this function and pass argument to function at that time, function give me log in console. But javascript function hasn't been called from mxml file.

I have added library for external interface and JS function in JS file also.

Answer (score 0):

You can call JS function from Flex like this

**In AS3**

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
ExternalInterface.call(“openNotes”, parameter);
}
```

**In Javascript**

```
function openNotes(notesUrl){
window.open(notesUrl, ”, ‘width=1000,height=600′);
}
```